# Execution time for an array output from different locations

Tags: c++

Does it makes any difference in execution time of a program if,I output an array from self declared function rather than using main function for it?
for example, using bubble sort as function for sorting and output it once from main and other time from function itself.

Comment: Regarding execution time: Possibly. Not necessarily. If the produced program is identical, then definitely not. It certainly has no effect on asymptotic time complexity.

Comment: Please show your code. Either there's a difference that can be **measured** or it doesn't matter.

Comment: Sorry, for that it was execution time @ Nicol Bolas

Comment: It could, functions do have some small overhead, but the amount with be very very small compared to all of the effort needed to write even a single character to the output. The readability and maintenance benefits of having a more-modular program may outweigh the cost. Start with well-engineered, maintainable code and only move to more optimized code when you've proven that you have A) a problem and B) the problem is the function call.

Comment: If you haven't already, turn up the compiler's optimization level and let it decide if it even needs a function. Compiler's are allowed to do anything they want so long as it doesn't change the program's observable behaviour (Search term: The As-if Rule). This includes quietly inlining a function that it decides provides no benefit to the compiled code.

Comment: @user4581301 I got it,thanks.

Answer (score -4):

Yes, because when you declare a function it takes bit more time than usual. But you can act the function as like the contents of the function is in main function. In that case you need to write "inline" before the function.

```
inline int add(int x, int y) {
    return x+y;
}

void main() {
    // some code
    int sum = add(2, 5);
    cout << sum <<endl;

    return;
}
```

Comment: Inline is not about inlining, sadly. I has a very little effect on compiler heuristics to actually inline the function. In this case, without optimisations, there is no inlining done. With optimisation, everything is fold into constant without the help of the inline keyword

Comment: _"... it takes bit more time than usual ..."_ That's not what's meant with _time complexity_

Comment: But,use of inline is not meaningful when function size becomes larger., as my function is large so.

Comment: @shivamkumar inline keyword works perfectly fine with large functions too, it will just make it longer to compile.

Comment: @ Guillaume Racicot Will overhead of function call become small as compared to execution time?

Comment: @FarukHossain happy to see you gaining knowledge about it. Some don't take it well.

Comment: @shivamkumar If you want to know if you're performant enough, look at the optimised assembly, mesure, benchmark and profile. Any other unmesured attempts are futile

Comment: @shivamkumar Also, premature optimisation is bad. Start by making good code and optimize when needed. The overhead of a non-virtual, direct call is negligible. If you also enable link time optimisation, there is no reason not making a function.

Comment: @Guillaume Racicot I am beginner in this platform now,I don't have too much idea about it,that's the reason why i joined this platform for gaining knowledge and skills from experience people like you,Thanks for helping.